# Unable to reset git template path

Tags: git

Git is reading a stale template path. This path used to be in my older VM. I had copied this git directory as it is to a new VM.
I tried removing "[commit] template" entry from `~/.gitconfig`, followed by `git commit` but it still gives me this error.
Then I tried removing all entries but to no avail.

```
$ git config --global --unset-all commit.template
$ git commit
fatal: could not read '/home/subtleseeker/main/commit-template.txt': No such file or directory
```

Any idea, where git is reading this path from?

```sh
$ git config --global commit.template /home/peeches/main/commit-template.txt
$ git config -l | grep template
commit.template=/home/peeches/main/commit-template.txt
commit.template=/home/subtleseeker/main/commit-template.txt
$ git config --global --unset-all commit.template
$ git config -l | grep template
commit.template=/home/subtleseeker/main/commit-template.txt
```

Git version: `git version 2.30.1`
OS: `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The config is local

```
commit.template=/home/peeches/main/commit-template.txt
commit.template=/home/subtleseeker/main/commit-template.txt
```

This shows two entries, git checks/outputs config [in the following order](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> When reading, the values are read from the system, global and **repository local configuration files** by default

Based on the order of the output in the question, the unwanted config entry is from the *local repository's git config*.

Therefore, to remove that reference, delete from local config:

```
$ git config --unset commit.template
```

*Note: The `--local` flag can be specified to be explicit - but that's the default behavior for write operations ([see the docs for more info](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)) so not necessary.*

That's almost certainly the case in the question though there are actually [more places git checks for config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES):

- `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`
- `$HOME/.config/git/config`
- `~/.gitconfig`
- `$GIT_DIR/config`
- `$GIT_DIR/config.worktree` (only if `extensions.worktreeConfig` is enabled)

If in doubt, check each in turn.

## Reproduction

Consider:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/so/.git/
➜  so git:(master) git config some.thing=local
error: invalid key: some.thing=local
➜  so git:(master) git config some.thing local
➜  so git:(master) git config --global some.thing global
➜  so git:(master) git config -l | grep some.thing
some.thing=global
some.thing=local
➜  so git:(master)
```

This simulates the situation in the question. Removing global config, does not affect the local config:

```
➜  so git:(master) git config --global --unset-all some.thing
➜  so git:(master) git config -l | grep some.thing
some.thing=local
➜  so git:(master)
```

But updating the local config does:

```
➜  so git:(master) git config --unset some.thing
➜  so git:(master) git config -l | grep some.thing
➜  so git:(master)
```